# Has the filial relation between Nightcrawler and Mystique, from the comics, been explicitly excluded from the X-Men Cinematic Universe?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, adaptation-comparison, x-men-apocalypse, x-men-dark-phoenix

In the comics, Nightcrawler is Mystique's son.

I could accept in *X2* that it just never comes up, as I don't recall the two being on screen much together (if at all). But with *X-Men: Apocalypse* and now *Dark Phoenix*, it seems like something the filmmakers decided to ignore or just did not realize.

Has this ever been addressed in interviews or the films themselves (different timelines or some other explanation)?

Comment: He could just not be Mystique's son.

Comment: If it's a decision that the writers of the movies have made, and they express it in the movie, is it necessary for them to talk about it publicly?

Comment: Has there ever been any connection between them in the on screen universe?

Comment: @JoeW  They are both X-men in Dark Phoenix (as in doing missions together).  And in Apocalypse (going from memory here) she saves him from some sort of organized fight/match (haven't seen it since it was in the theatre).

Comment: @Adamant  Sorry, should of clarified a bit.  In most other instances I've seen (comic books and verifying on Wikipedia [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightcrawler_(comics)#Family_relations]) Nightcrawler is Mystique's son.

Comment: That is not the connection you are asking about or that I was talking about. As far as I can remember there has never been any relation between the two in the movies

Comment: @JoeW  Agreed.  Outside of the movies I thought this relationship was established and was wondering if it had ever been addressed why the films went in a different direction (either in the films themselves and I missed it, or by interviews with the film makers or something).

Comment: It is common for films to vary from the original comic (indeed, all) sources.  I can't think of a single based-on-a-book/comic/story movie I've ever seen that didn't vary from the original source.  I wonder, though, about the somewhat aggressive title to your post.  Please note that no Stack permits rants (although based on your comments, I don't believe that's what you intended).

Comment: There is a scene of them together in X2. IIRC from the dvd commentary, Singer deliberately put it in as an homage to their relationship in the comics.

Comment: @JBH  Sorry about the title, meant to be more light-hearted sarcasm than a rant.  I can change it if you'd like.

Comment: @Darren That is a good example of what I was hoping to find out!  I am however more curious about the more recent films and if there has been any mention about their relationship (even if it's just a simple "yep, we wanted both characters but they aren't related in our version" or something).

Comment: @PawnInGameOfLife, no big deal.  Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: While it's never addressed, First Class does have Mystique joining the same mutant organization as Nightcrawler's father from the comics 21 years before a young Nightcrawler shows up in Apocalypse (his actor was 19 at the time). It could be they were leaving the possibility open, much like Days of Future Past did with Quicksilver's paternity. Unofficially, there's a bit in the Apocalypse blooper reel where Mystique introduces Nightcrawler as her son, so it seems very likely the filmmakers were aware of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they're not supposed to be related, even if you as an out-of-universe movie spectator know their comic backstory. There are two pieces of evidence for that.

The first is the audio commentary of *X-Men 2*, over the Mystique/Nightcrawler scene below (timestamp 1:14:13 in the movie, and therefore in the commentary):

> Alright, this is uh, this is a big moment, 'cause this is another one of those scenes I think where... It's one of the first scenes I kind of took a step back, **because being a nerd/geek, I really wanted to see a moment between Mystique and Nightcrawler. And fans of the comics know that in the comics, they're mother and son. So I really wanted to have a scene that would hint at maybe that's where we were going, but not necessarily there yet.** And I think it's also a moment that kind of sums up Mystique's point of view, which we have never really heard up until now.

The second one is located in *The Art of X-Men: The Last Stand* (2006), [page 47](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAvsT.jpg):

> After the cancellation of “Ms. Marvel,” Claremont and Byrne brought the character over to “Uncanny X-Men” as the leader of a new Brotherhood of Evil Mutants. In the course of
>   the Brotherhood’s battle with the X-Men, Nightcrawler notices the physical similarities between himself and Mystique and wonders aloud whether they are connected. **Two decades later it is finally revealed that Mystique is Nightcrawler's mother, a part of X-Men lore that has not been adopted by the movies.**

[image: original text with a Pyro illustration]

Now arguably [Peter Sanderson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Sanderson), who wrote the "X-Men: From Comic To Screen" text above, was not involved in the making of the movie, but it's reasonable to think he talked with the movie's creators. Furthermore, the above is an official Marvel publication, and I doubt Marvel would have accepted to print such a phrasing if they wanted to have room for a potential "Nightcrawler is Mystique's son" part in the movies.

Comment: Thank you for both the great answer and un-deleting/editing this question!